# Best Way to Delete an Element from a Multidimensional Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I just deleted an element in my array using this code:

```
delete chckboxIDs[0][0];
```

This is what the data in my array looks like now:

[image]

Now my array has an empty cell which breaks the code because i loop through it based on its length in other places in my program causing a null value exception. How do i get rid of this empty space?

If i shift all the elements down until it was in the last position wouldnt it still be there and still break the code? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: None of these are removing elements from a multidimensional array.

Comment: I tried chckboxIDs.splice(chckboxIDs[0][0], 1); to remove the first element, but it deleted all of them.

Comment: The array element is an array. Using `Array.prototype.splice` on the nested array gives the result you asked for. I'd suggest reading up on [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You try using `splice` function, `delete` is not really advisable in removing element in an array or 2d array in Javascript

```
chckboxIDs[row].splice(col, 1);
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. That makes sense now. Couldn't figure out how to adapt the splice code I've seen in other posts for regular arrays into a multidimensional format.